# How can I relabel an HFS+ partition?

Tags: partition, hfs+

I am attempting to rename an HFS+ partition for a friend to use. After formatting, the volume appears as "untitled". Gparted and Nemo cannot seem to relabel it due to their own limitations for dealing with HFS.
I can read/write normally, but currently cannot edit the GPT label, which is what I want to do. How can I do this?

Comment: In GPT the label is the partition name. `parted` supports changing it, so `gparted` should too.

Comment: My apologies, `gparted` does not seem to have a function to change a partition name, at least not on the surface. But `parted` can.

Comment: Of course you could do it with the Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer seems to be that `parted` and other command line tools are not capable of writing labels to HFS/HFS+ partition schemes at the moment, possibly ever. Parted being the most feature-rich tool for editing partitions, and that in itself depending on `hfsprogs`, which does not seem to support HFS+ relabeling at this time, it does not seem possible. Given that this basic functionality has not been added in the 4 years since I asked this question, **parted will probably never support HFS+ relabelling**, though I'd be happy to be proven wrong.
Source: https://gparted.org/features.php

Answer (score 0):

In Linux `gparted` (1.4.0) each HFS+ partition has a "Label File System" menu entry but it is greyed out so I do not know if it is possible.

In Mac OS X:

with

```
% diskutil list
```

find the identifier, here 'disk0s1'.

```
% diskutil mount disk0s1
% diskutil rename disk0s1 whatever
```

Beware: NAME in Mac OS X is the same as label in Linux.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. This is what i did:

First turn off journaling on the HFS drive.
To do this you need a OSX system.

After that, on linux:
Unmount the drive, create a folder in the desired location with the new name.
After that you can remount the drive to the folder.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: How does that change the filesystem label?  You only seem to have changed the mountpoint.